# How would I create a function that decrease the n with recursion in python

Tags: python, recursion

How would I go about creating a function which will print the numbers and all the numbers below it until 1 through recursion?

For example:

```
print_down_rec(5)
```

will return

```
5
4
3
2
1
```

Comment: Which part are you able to write? Are you able to write a Python function that obtains a parameter and displays it? What's missing then?

Comment: Do you have to use recursion?

Answer (score 1):

This could be a possible solution:

```
def print_(n):
        if n >= 1:
            print n
            print_(n-1)
```

Comment: Definitely. You can easily compare it with other solutions.

Comment: Now get rid of the unnecessary parens and it looks even simpler: `if n >= 1`.

Answer (score 1):

When writing a recursive function, it's a good idea to start with the base case. In this instance, this would happen when `n==1`:

```
def print_down_rec(n):
    if n==1:
        print(n)
```

The next step would be to think of an inductive case. For `n` that is greater than 1, we want to display `n` and then invoke the function with `n-1`:

```
    else:
        print(n)
        print_down_rec(n-1)
```

Finally, we want to call the function with our desired arguments. Putting it all together:

```
def print_down_rec(n):
    if n==1:
        print(n)
    else:
        print(n)
        print_down_rec(n-1)
print_down_rec(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version. Two lines of code (three if we count definition). Prints out the new value before checking if we should run the function one more time. Not much difference when you just need to count from 5 to 1, but can save some time should we have some logic to do with the value and if number of values is much more than 5

```
def print_down_rec(n): 
    print n 
    print_down_rec(n-1) if n>1 else print "End"
```